# How to I tell if a client process is dead?

Tags: sql-server, client-server

**Background**

We have worker processes that read “jobs” from a table in SqlServer then write the results back to other tables.  One or more machines run one or more worker processes.
A single SqlSever database (sometimes clustered) is at the centre of our world, so is likely to be where the solution should live.

We need a system that detaches if the worker process or the machine it is running on fails.   (Not being able to talk to the database is a bad as the worker process failing in any other way.)

The worker process can, if needed, keep a connection and transaction open to the SQL Server while processing a job.

**Options I have come up with.**

Use database locks:

- Start a transaction in the worker process and lock a row (or application lock)
- We know the worker process is OK, provided the row is still locked
- If the worker process aborts for any reason the SQL Server will abort the transaction and remove the lock.

Use a watchdog timer:

- Have a row for each worker process in a table
- The worker process updates a “last time OK” column in the row often
- If the column has not been updated for a long time, the worker process is dead.
- The SqlServer UST time is used, so as to avoid problem with different time on each machine.

Is there another option I have not thought about?

What problems do you see with the above options?

---

*If you care our worker process are written in .NET and run on Windows servers.  We don’t need to be able to port the solution to a different database vendor; we only need to surport Sql Server 2005 and 2008*

Comment: We do exactly this, works like a charm.  Kind of pro that you thought to use server time beforehand, we learned that only after a wintertime conversion ;)

Comment: @Andomar, do you get problems with the customers changing the time on SqlServer?

Comment: Kerberos requires all computers in an active directory domain to have the same idea of UTC.  As long as you use `getutcdate()` in SQL, I wouldn't expect any problem whatsoever.

Comment: @Andomar, please change your comments into an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do exactly this, works like a charm. Kind of pro that you thought to use server time beforehand, we learned that only after a wintertime conversion ;)

Kerberos requires all computers in an active directory domain to have the same idea of UTC. As long as you use getutcdate() in SQL, I wouldn't expect any problem whatsoever.